# Dynamically change placeholder at runtime

Tags: wffm, placeholders, webforms

I have a web page with two placeholders, A and B. In Sitecore I inserted a WFFM form in placeholder B.

Based on a the value of a checkbox in Sitecore, I want the WFFM form to be inserted into either placeholder A or B, at runtime (i.e not permanently).

E.g:

the checkbox is checked --> the form is inserted in placeholder A
the checkbox is not checked --> the form is inserted in placeholder B

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using conditional rendering rules.

You would need to add the Form to the page twice, but it will only get rendered once.

Take this example. I have 2 promo renderings and I want them to render based on the value of a field (could be a checkbox) on an item:

[image]

Now add a new rule:

[image]

In the rule, you can use the `where the **specific** field **compares to** **value**` condition.

This will use a field on the context item to determine true/false.

[image]

Now you can either hide the component as default and show when the rule meets the conditions. Then add the form a second time, add the condition, but set the opposite options for hiding/showing. And put the 2 renderings into the different placeholders.

This way you don't have to do any extra coding.

If the field you need is *not* on the context item, you may need to create a custom condition so that you can specify the item as well as the field.

I have used this method before and it has worked well.